# Classes and inheritance in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

What on earth is going on here?
How can the `Daughter`-class contain data that's been set in `Brother`, and how should I make sure that data set in sibling classes doesn't interfere with eachother?

```
class Parent 
  data: {}

class Child extends Parent
  age: 10

Son = new Child
Son.data.name = "John Doe"

Daughter = new Child
console.log Daughter.data # => { name: 'John Doe' }
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, its worth noting that Son and Daughter are not classes, like you refer to them in your question. They are in fact instances of `Child`, which extends the `Parent` prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take your CS code and put it in the side-by-side editor on CoffeeScript's site (http://coffeescript.org/), you'll see that `data` is on the prototype of the `Parent` "class".  Think of that prototype being the template for new functions (classes) that you create.  That prototype either contains other functions or it contains variables available to all instances (like an OO static variable).

You're adding `name` to a "static" variable `data`.  It will then be available to all instances that "derive" from `Parent`.

I'm not sure of the inner workings that go on there, but coming from an OO world, that's how I interpret it.  I hope this helps.

**GENERATED CODE VIA COFFEESCRIPT'S SITE**

```
var Child, Daughter, Parent, Son,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

Parent = (function() {

  function Parent() {}

  Parent.prototype.data = {};

  return Parent;

})();

Child = (function(_super) {

  __extends(Child, _super);

  function Child() {
    return Child.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  Child.prototype.age = 10;

  return Child;

})(Parent);

Son = new Child;

Son.data.name = "John Doe";

Daughter = new Child;

alert(Daughter.data.name);
```

**UPDATE**
Just noticed that the CS side-by-side window has a link feature.  Here's a [link](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Parent%20%0A%20%20data%3a%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%0A%20%20age%3a%2010%0A%0ASon%20=%20new%20Child%0ASon.data.name%20=%20%22John%20Doe%22%0A%0ADaughter%20=%20new%20Child%0Aalert%20Daughter.data.name) to the side-by-side code.

**UPDATE #2**

In response to your question in the comments, I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but you could do something like this:

```
class Parent 
  #data: {}

class Child extends Parent
  constructor: (@name) ->
  age: 10
  sayHi: -> alert "Hi " + @name


Son = new Child "John Doe"

Daughter = new Child "Sarah Jane"

Son.sayHi()
Daughter.sayHi()
```

Perhaps keep the `name` variable (or the entire `data` variable) at the parent level and set it via a constructor and access it via a parent function.

Comment: Best not to use terms like "static variable" to avoid muddying the difference between prototypal vs classical.

Comment: Thanks @MattWhipple.  I adjusted my text a bit.  I was trying to answer from an OO perspective as I'm assuming that the OP is looking at the code from that point of view.  Perhaps a big assumption on my part.  :)

Comment: Yeah drawing comparisons is the way to go so long as they have distinctions with them.  It seems like one of the problems with the OP is that he's already looking at the code too much from that point of view so there should be reminders of "this isn't what you probably think it is"

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation, but how would I work around this? I tried creating a constructor in `Parent` resetting the `data` property, but still makes no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: I added an update as a possible workaround (a very simple example), but maybe it will set you in the right direction.  I hope it helps!

Comment: You should not uppercase the first letter of an instance, it's confusing that Son and Daughter are not classes.

Comment: @SuperSkunk agreed - I wouldn't code it that way.  But that's how the OP posed the question, so I was attempting to answer in that style.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be, that you're not using a constructor to initialize `data` for each instance. Instead, you're giving it an initial value that happens to sit on `Animal` which is mutable. Whenever you assign to `instance.data.attribute`, you are in fact modifying that shared object. If you had used an `data: 1` instead, you would not have seen this sharing behavior.

This fixes your problem:

```
class Parent 
  constructor: () ->
    @data = {}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not that well versed with JavaScript's prototypal inheritance, so the technical details I provided may not be correct, but the description of the phenomenon seems accurate.

### Difference when compiled

```
class Parent 
  staticD: {}
  constructor: ->
    @data = {}
```

Compiles to:

```
Parent = (function() {

  Parent.prototype.staticD = {};

  function Parent() {
    this.data = {};
  }

  return Parent;

})();
```

As you can see `staticD` is initalized only once at the creation of the "class", `data` on the other hand is initialized in the constructor and assigned a new, empty object every time an instance is created.

Comment: Sorry. Tried that as well and it makes no difference unfortunately

Comment: @Industrial That is weird, because when I try that on CoffeeScript.org it works. Please try again.